# Change information in a CSV file using info from the first one in python

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to edit a CSV file using informations from a first one. That doesn't seem simple to me as I should filter multiple things. Let's explain my problem.

I have two CSV files, let's say patch.csv and origin.csv. Output csv file should have the same pattern as origin.csv, but with corrected values.

I want to replace trip_headsign column fields in origin.csv using forward_line_name column in patch.csv if direction_id field in origin.csv row is 0, or using backward_line_name if direction_id is 1.

I want to do this only if the part of the line_id value in patch.csv between ":" and ":" symbols is the same as the part of route_id value in origin.csv before the ":" symbol.

I know how to replace a whole line, but not only some parts, especially that I sometimes have to look only part of a value.

Here is a sample of origin.csv:

```
route_id,service_id,trip_id,trip_headsign,direction_id,block_id

210210109:001,2913,70405957139549,70405957,0,
210210109:001,2916,70405961139553,70405961,1,
```

and a sample of patch.csv:

```
line_id,line_code,line_name,forward_line_name,forward_direction,backward_line_name,backward_direction,line_color,line_sort,network_id,commercial_mode_id,contributor_id,geometry_id,line_opening_time,line_closing_time

OIF:100110010:10OIF439,10,Boulogne Pont de Saint-Cloud - Gare d'Austerlitz,BOULOGNE / PONT DE ST CLOUD - GARE D'AUSTERLITZ,OIF:SA:8754700,GARE D'AUSTERLITZ - BOULOGNE / PONT DE ST CLOUD,OIF:SA:59400,DFB039,91,OIF:439,metro,OIF,geometry:line:100110010:10,05:30:00,25:47:00
OIF:210210109:001OIF30,001,FFOURCHES LONGUEVILLE PROVINS,Place Mérot - GARE DE LONGUEVILLE,,GARE DE LONGUEVILLE - Place Mérot,OIF:SA:63:49,000000   1,OIF:30,bus,OIF,,05:39:00,19:50:00
```

Each file has hundred of lines I need to parse and edit this way.

Based on mhopeng answer, I obtained that code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
from __future__ import print_function
import fileinput
import sys

# first get the route info from patch.csv
f = open(sys.argv[1])
d = open(sys.argv[2])
# ignore header line
#line1 = f.readline()
#line2 = d.readline()
# get line of data
for line1 in f.readline():
    line1 = f.readline().split(',')
    route_id = line1[0].split(':')[1] # '210210109'
    route_forward = line1[3]
    route_backward = line1[5]
    line_code = line1[1]

# process origin.csv and replace lines in-place
    for line in fileinput.input(sys.argv[2], inplace=1):
        line2 = d.readline().split(',')
        num_route = line2[0].split(':')[0]
# prevent lines with same route_id but different code to be considered as the same line 
        if line.startswith(route_id) and (num_route == line_code):
        if line.startswith(route_id):
            newline = line.split(',')
            if newline[4] == 0:
                newline[3] = route_backward
            else:
                newline[3] = route_forward
            print('\t'.join(newline),end="")
        else:
            print(line,end="")
```

But unfortunately, that doesn't push the right forward or backward_line_name in trip_headsign (always forward), and finally triggers that error, before finishing parsing the file:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./GTFS_enhancer_headsigns.py", line 28, in 
    if newline[4] == 0:
IndexError: list index out of range

Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: It would help if you edited the question to include an example of your two input csv files and what your output csv file should look like.

Comment: Just edited with samples from both csv files, here the line_id part I want to compare is 100110010 and I want to compare it to the 210210109 route_id part. If both are identical, I want to perform the changes.

Comment: Are you sure that the header line and the blank line after the header are not causing problems? If you are reading the blank line, then newline[4] will not exist.

Comment: Also the original sample file snippets were tab-delimited (and didn't have this blank line after the header). So don't forget to change all of the `'\t'` to `','`.

Comment: Your code looks like it compares each line of one file to only one line in the other file (the line with the same line number). Is this your intention? If so, this is not apparent from the question statement. Or can any line in patch.csv be used to modify any line in origin.csv?

Comment: @mhopeng and others: I just bountied this project $25 with few more things there https://bountify.co/gK if everything works.

Answer (score 0):

pandas is convenient for handling csv files.  I would use something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

origin = pd.read_csv('origin.csv',index_col=None)
patch  = pd.read_csv('patch.csv', index_col=None)

# Create match_keys for matching origin.csv from patch.line_id

patch['match_key'] = [x.split(':')[1] for x in patch.line_id.values]
origin['match_key'] = [x.split(':')[0] for x in origin.route_id.values]

for i,key in enumerate(origin.match_key.values):
    p = patch[patch.match_key == key]
    if len(p) == 1:
        if (origin.direction_id[i] == 0):
            origin.trip_headsign[i] = p.forward_line_name.values[0]
        elif (origin.direction_id[i] == 1):
            origin.trip_headsign[i] = p.backward_line_name.values[0]

origin.to_csv('new_origin.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) module from the standard library for in-place editing of a file. Something like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import fileinput

# first get the route info from patch.csv
f = open('patch.csv')
# discard header line
line = f.readline()
# get line of data
line = f.readline().split('\t')
route_id = line[0].split(':')[1] # '210210109'
route_forward = line[3]
route_backward = line[5]
f.close()

# process origin.csv and replace lines in-place
for line in fileinput.input('origin.csv', inplace=1):
    if line.startswith(route_id):
        newline = line.split('\t')
        if newline[4] == 0:
            newline[3] = route_backward
        else:
            newline[3] = route_forward
        print('\t'.join(newline),end="")
    else:
        print(line,end="")
```

Comment: mhopeng, thanks for your help. I got this error when running this script:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./GTFS_enhancer_headsigns.py", line 13, in <module>
    route_forward = line[3]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Ok, I found where the problem was and fixed it. Now, I need to parse and replace in all lines in origin.csv versus all lines in patch.csv. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the `littletable` module as a small-footprint Python module that makes it easy to work with tabular data without having to use heavyweight guns like pandas. `littletable` Tables can import/export CSV data, as well as various table methods.

Start by loading the data into Tables:

```
import littletable as lt

# Actual script would import from CSV files - for example, just use given sample data
# origin = lt.Table().csv_import("origin.csv")
# patch = lt.Table().csv_import("patch.csv")

origin = lt.Table().csv_import("""\
route_id,service_id,trip_id,trip_headsign,direction_id,block_id
210210109:001,2913,70405957139549,70405957,0,
210210109:001,2916,70405961139553,70405961,1,
310210109:001,2913,70405957139549,70405957,0,
""")

patch = lt.Table().csv_import("""\
line_id,line_code,line_name,forward_line_name,forward_direction,backward_line_name,backward_direction,line_color,line_sort,network_id,commercial_mode_id,contributor_id,geometry_id,line_opening_time,line_closing_time
OIF:100110010:10OIF439,10,Boulogne Pont de Saint-Cloud - Gare d'Austerlitz,BOULOGNE / PONT DE ST CLOUD - GARE D'AUSTERLITZ,OIF:SA:8754700,GARE D'AUSTERLITZ - BOULOGNE / PONT DE ST CLOUD,OIF:SA:59400,DFB039,91,OIF:439,metro,OIF,geometry:line:100110010:10,05:30:00,25:47:00
OIF:210210109:001OIF30,001,FFOURCHES LONGUEVILLE PROVINS,Place Mérot - GARE DE LONGUEVILLE,,GARE DE LONGUEVILLE - Place Mérot,OIF:SA:63:49,000000   1,OIF:30,bus,OIF,,05:39:00,19:50:00
""")
```

Add field to patch for lookup by route_key, and a unique index for it

```
patch.add_field("route_key", lambda rec: rec.line_id.split(":")[1])
patch.create_index("route_key", unique=True)
```

Show the "before" origin table (uses the `rich` module)

```
origin("initial data").present()
```

Which will look like this:

```
                                      initial data

  Route_Id        Service_Id   Trip_Id          Trip_Headsign   Direction_Id   Block_Id 
 ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  210210109:001   2913         70405957139549   70405957        0
  210210109:001   2916         70405961139553   70405961        1
  310210109:001   2913         70405957139549   70405957        0
```

Now iterate through origin, extracting the route key from the route_id, and getting the data from the patch table, keyed by route_key:

```
for line_no, rec in enumerate(origin, start=1):
    route_key = rec.route_id.split(":")[0]
    if route_key not in patch.by.route_key:
        print("no such route key {!r} in patch.csv (origin.csv/{})".format(route_key, line_no))
        continue

    patch_rec = patch.by.route_key[route_key]
    if rec.direction_id == "0":
        rec.trip_headsign = patch_rec.forward_line_name
    else:
        rec.trip_headsign = patch_rec.backward_line_name
```

I added a line in origin with an invalid route_key, and we see this message:

```
no such route key '310210109' in patch.csv (origin.csv/3)
```

Display the updated table:

```
origin("updated data").present()
```

Now looks like:

```
                                                updated data

  Route_Id        Service_Id   Trip_Id          Trip_Headsign                       Direction_Id   Block_Id 
 ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  210210109:001   2913         70405957139549   Place Mérot - GARE DE LONGUEVILLE   0
  210210109:001   2916         70405961139553   GARE DE LONGUEVILLE - Place Mérot   1
  310210109:001   2913         70405957139549   70405957                            0
```

Now save modified origin records to new CSV file (or just overwrite origin.csv)

```
origin.csv_export("updated_origin.csv")
```

Or use a StringIO to capture as a string, during testing

```
import io
example = io.StringIO()
origin.csv_export(example)
print(example.getvalue())
```

Gives:

```
route_id,service_id,trip_id,trip_headsign,direction_id,block_id
210210109:001,2913,70405957139549,Place Mérot - GARE DE LONGUEVILLE,0,
210210109:001,2916,70405961139553,GARE DE LONGUEVILLE - Place Mérot,1,
310210109:001,2913,70405957139549,70405957,0,
```